# Heroku H14 (no web processes running) + Spring-boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, heroku, spring-boot

Sorry if this question is repeated  but I cannot find a solution in other questions.

I'm trying to deploy my `Spring-boot` application on heroku. I'm hosting the database, but when i try to deploy I'm getting this error on the logs in heroku.

```
2016-01-29T05:08:05.730937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" h
    ost=naturaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=39586950-d3fb-463c-9b21-458ae41b2f36 fwd="190.139.xx.xxx" dyno= connect= service=
     status=503 bytes=
    2016-01-29T05:08:06.641002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/fav
    icon.ico" host=naturaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=75e51dfb-58f1-4524-9a66-52605573097e fwd="190.139.xx.xxx" dyno= connec
    t= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can someone explain me what to do?

I already use the command `heroku ps:scale web` but still getting the same error.

If you need my code, please tell me!

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

After adding my `Procfile` with `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar`

I'm getting the following errors on my log:

```
    PS C:\Users\Paulo> heroku logs --tail --app naturaapp
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000435+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2016-01-29T23:59:36.950259+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-29 23:59:36.950  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000476+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000281+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000644+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000899+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000537+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000841+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000981+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001276+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.000592+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001057+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001206+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001422+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001603+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001134+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001349+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001717+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001512+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001860+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001810+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001812+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001661+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002285+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002345+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001914+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.arg.juy.natura.NaturaApplication.main(NaturaApplication.java:19)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001987+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002119+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2016-01-29T23:59:37.001543+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002217+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002479+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002615+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002671+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002221+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002409+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002556+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002737+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002806+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.003012+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.003082+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002864+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.002959+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.003136+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
2016-01-29T23:59:37.003239+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 22 more
2016-01-29T23:59:37.003194+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
2016-01-29T23:59:36.895820+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-29 23:59:36.895  WARN 3 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2016-01-29T23:59:36.957188+00:00 app[web.1]:  java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
2016-01-29T23:59:36.957183+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-29 23:59:36.957  WARN 3 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
2016-01-29T23:59:36.957190+00:00 app[web.1]:  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
2016-01-29T23:59:36.957191+00:00 app[web.1]:  com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989715+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-29 23:59:36.988 ERROR 3 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989720+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989722+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989724+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989725+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989726+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989727+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989729+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989728+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989729+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989731+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989738+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989740+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989739+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989741+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989741+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989742+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989743+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989743+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989744+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.arg.juy.natura.NaturaApplication.main(NaturaApplication.java:19)[Natura-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989745+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72-cedar14]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989746+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72-cedar14]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989747+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72-cedar14]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989747+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72-cedar14]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989748+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [Natura-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989749+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72-cedar14]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989750+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989756+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989762+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989763+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989763+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989764+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989764+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989765+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989766+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989771+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989773+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989772+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989773+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989775+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989774+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989775+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989778+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989778+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 22 common frames omitted
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989777+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.989776+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
2016-01-29T23:59:36.999565+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-29 23:59:36.999  WARN 3 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@61a1574f of typeclass org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler)
2016-01-29T23:59:38.029307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-29T23:59:38.042223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-29T23:59:40.076012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=naturaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=8e5f90d5-40eb-470e-a765-f13eaa718b4d fwd="190.139.13.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-29T23:59:41.412282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=naturaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=47328aa0-860c-46ef-a345-4b17190a8329 fwd="190.139.13.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

And my `application.properties` have all that information that can't found on the deploying

```
db.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
db.url: jdbc:postgresql://190.139.xx.xxx:5432/poo2015
db.username: pooxxxx
db.password: pooxxxx

# Hibernate    
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.arg.juy.natura
```

Comment: Add your Procfile, project structure and other relevant pieces

Comment: Did u get any errors after executing the command `heroku ps:scale web`

Comment: i'm getting the following error using the `ps:scale`  

`PS C:\Users\Paulo> heroku ps:scale web=1 --app naturaapp
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    Couldn't find that formation.`

Comment: i've added the Procfile but still getting the same error in my logs deploying.
 and this error doing the ` ps:scale`
`Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free.
D:/Archivos de programa/Heroku/lib/heroku/analytics.rb:16:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (N
otImplementedError)
        from D:/Archivos de programa/Heroku/lib/heroku/analytics.rb:16:in `submit'
        from D:/Archivos de programa/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:34:in `start'
        from D:/Archivos de programa/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry if this answer is too late.

That error was because the deploying exceed the timeout connecting to my local database. I solved ot using the database that heroku provides me for free.